# Matplotlib figure not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have all of my graphs working, so now I am trying to scale my plots down to a relatively small size (3x3in). I added the figure command and the graph goes blank. Right size, just blank. I'm obviously missing something basic but it's beating me.  When I comment it out, it shows fine ( if a bit big). When I include it, it blanks the image.

What am I doing incorrectly ?

```
plt.setp(line[lindex], linewidth=1.0)
plt.setp(line[lindex+1], linewidth=2.0)
plt.xlabel("Months")
plt.ylabel("Score")
plt.title(CurrAppName + "- by month")
plt.legend()
# plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why _wouldn't_ you include [tag:matplotlib] tag in a question named: _"Matplotlib figure not working"_?

Comment: That was a miss. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is your whole code, just put the `plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))` as the first line. Here, declaring `plt.figure(...)` in the end means you are creating a whole new plot after you've drawn into the last one. You don't want that.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you - I dont want that at all.